# How Can I deserialize a json that is an object with an array? using Newtonsoft xamarin

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, deserialization

I am using Xamarin forms and Newtonsoft to deserialize

It doesn't work:

```
var itens = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.Loja>>(json);
```

Here is my JSON:

```
{
  "one": {
    "two": [
      {
        "cod": 142,
        "nome": "name",
        "phone": "23423",
        "endereco": "address",
        "cidade": "city"
      },
      {
        "cod": 142,
        "nome": "name",
        "phone": "23423",
        "endereco": "address",
        "cidade": "city"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Show the code for `Model.Loja`.

Comment: "one" is an object including "two" which is array. You should have interesting model

Comment: lol...its an example...but I solved it with substring :D
Thank u guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the "[ ]".
I used

```
response = json.Substring(json.IndexOf('['));
response = json.Substring(0, json.LastIndexOf(']') + 1);
```

And solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Your model needs to match your JSON structure.  Try using these classes:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public One one { get; set; }
}

public class One
{
    public List<Loja> two { get; set; }
}

public class Loja
{
    public int cod { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string endereco { get; set; }
    public string cidade { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize like this:

```
List<Loja> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json).one.two;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a specific model class for that json, try to use http://json2csharp.com/,

and then you can parse it using newtonsoft.

If you are using json2chsarp then your specific class will called RootObject, but you can rename it to match your model.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourSpecificClass>(json);
```